# PHP addcslashes() function syntax

Tags: php, escaping

The manual page for the PHP [addcslashes() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) gives the following example:

```
addcslashes($not_escaped, "\0..\37!@\177..\377");
```

to escape all ASCII characters between 0 and 31 (= 037 octal).  A user suggests the following improvement:

```
addcslashes($not_escaped, "\0..\37!@\@\177..\377");
```

to "protect original, innocent backslashes from stripcslashes".

Is there any documentation for the format of the `charlist` parameter?  Specifically, what is the interpretation of the `!@` sequence in the first example, and the `!@\@` sequence in the second?

Comment: Wow, you have me stumped on this one. I'm not the best at reading C but I can't find any logic that specifically handles that. There's a vague reference that `!@` creates multiple ranges but it is in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to find the obvious.

!@ is no special sequence, that are single characters which should be escaped.
The only special input for addcslashes is *char..char* for a range.

\0..\37!@\177..\377 escapes the range *0..\37*, the character *!*, the character *@* and the range *\177..\377*

The suggestion with `!@\@` is invalid (not clean) in my opinion.
`\@` is not masked in php (there is no special meaning behind it like \n) and it will be the same. So \ and @ (for a second time) are added to the character list.
No magic and no special sequence behind this.
The clean solution when you want to escape all non printable characters (0-37 and 177+), the @, !, \ is:

```
"\0..\37!@\\\177..\377"
```

Comment: Nice debugging! What's weird is that is still the escape sequence that PHP's mime type generator is still using today: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c3bbcff5e603ee18cdc439a3e567464b4432538d/sapi/cli/generate_mime_type_map.php#L73

Comment: thats wired... 
the file was added 6 years ago, the comment is 18 yeas old. Maybe it was copied without inspection?

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like this is one of those strings which gets copied throughout the codebase without anyone really knowing what it's for.